# Word counting for thread in java program

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

My task was to Write a program to find the word count for all the files inside a directory (for also nested
directories) by creating process or threads.I was required to create a process or a thread for each file, and
this process or thread will count the number of words inside the file. When the process or thread
finishes the counting, it will write the file name and how many words there are inside this file. At the
end, a total number of words will be displayed for all the files.
For my task I made the following program:

```
package cloudS;

import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File; 

public class WordCount1 
{
    private static int count = 0; 

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String path = "C:\\Users\\$mit\\Desktop";
        path = path + "\\" + args[0];
        String filename = args[0];  
        task1(filename, path);
        task2(filename, path);
        System.out.println("Total Word " + count);
    }

    public static void task2 (String filename, String path)
    {
        File file = new File (path);
        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            String [] name = file.list();
            String [] paths = new String [name.length];  

            for (int i=0; i<name.length; i++)
            {
                paths[i] = path + "\\" + name[i];
                task2(name[i], paths[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            BufferedReader br = null; 
            FileReader fr = null; 

            int wordCount = 0; 
            try 
            {
                fr = new FileReader(path);
                br = new BufferedReader (fr);

                String line = null; 

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String [] array = line.split(" ");
                    wordCount = wordCount + array.length;
                    count = count + array.length;
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("IOException");
            }

            System.out.println (filename + "\t" + wordCount);

            try 
            {
                br.close(); 
                fr.close(); 
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("IOException");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void task1 (String filename, String path)
    {
            BufferedReader br = null; 
            FileReader fr = null; 

            int wordCount = 0; 
            try 
            {
                fr = new FileReader(path);
                br = new BufferedReader (fr);

                String line = null; 

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String [] array = line.split(" ");
                    wordCount = wordCount + array.length;
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("IOException");
            }

            System.out.println (filename + "\t" + wordCount);

            try 
            {
                br.close(); 
                fr.close(); 
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("IOException");
            }
    }


}
```

After running the program i am getting the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at cloudS.WordCount1.main(WordCount1.java:15)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Er... where are your Threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you pass any arguments to the program? Looks like your args array is probably empty, but you're trying to use `args[0]`.

Comment: can you please tell me on which line i made the mistake?

Comment: yeah i got about the args error, but how to fix that?Your help is appreciated sir.

Comment: @Aniruddh When you see "`WordCount1.java:15`" in your exception, the `15` is the line number of the error. I would suggest to seek a mentor to assist you with this code, since even if you run the program with arguments in order to pass this first issue, I think you'll hit other issues.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot Sir !